# How to write 2D data containing excel errors using c# VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have Excel functions where I am writing 2D data using VSTO.  In some cases, I need to write an Excel error like #N/A.  How do I do this? I have attempted to use XlCVError.xlErrNA but it just writes the value 2042.

Codewise, I have the following:

```
public void WriteChanges(int startRow, int startCol, int endRow, int endCol, int rows, int columns, IItems items)
{
    object[,] data = new object[rows, columns];
    var startCell = (Range)this.sheet.Cells[startRow, startCol];
    var endCell = (Range)this.sheet.Cells[endRow, endCol];
    var rangeToWrite = this.sheet.Range[startCell, endCell];
    var error = new ExcelError();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        int row = item.Row;
        int col = item.Column;

        if (!(item.Value is eExcelErrror))
        {
            data[row, col] = item.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            data[row, col] = this.error.ToVstoError((eExcelError)item.Value);
        }
    }

    rangeToWrite.Value = data;
}

public enum eExcelError
{
    ExcelErrorValue = 2015,
    ExcelErrorNA = 2042
}

public class ExcelError
{
    public object ToVstoNativeError(eExcelError value)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case eExcelError.ExcelErrorNA:
                return this.VstoNoData();
            case eExcelError.ExcelErrorValue:
            default:
                return this.VstoErrorValue();
        }
    }

    public object VstoNoData()
    {
        return XlCVError.xlErrNA;
    }

    public object VstoErrorValue()
    {
        return XlCVError.xlErrValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this to work by making the specific values equal to a formula. I still wonder if there is an actual way to use the built-in enum though. For example, instead of XlCVError.xlErrNa, I have a different return line in methods such as VstoNoData that do the following:  return "=#N/A";

Comment: You can use a formula such as `=NA()`

Comment: Hi Tim, is there a list of formulas (i.e. NA, VALUE, etc)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to set Excel errors into a cell... which kind of makes sense. If you were the user and you saw a `#DIV/0` error in a cell, but there was no formula, or you saw a `#NAME` error and you inserted the defined name into the names manager and it still didn't work, that would be very confusing.

What I would recommend doing is `cell.Value = "#REF"`. At least this way the user can see that this is just a string and not an actual error from Excel that they may fall into a rabbit hole chasing.

*Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.errors?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_Range_Errors* (note: `get` only)